# push view error in SWRevealViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, swrevealviewcontroller

I use `SWRevealViewController` in root view and make custom static view with two button in custom class. 
If I click button - push nextView controller from custom custom class

```
UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

UINavigationController *navigationController = [storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"historyGoodsView"];

SWRevealViewController *rootViewController = (SWRevealViewController *)[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]rootViewController];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];

[navController pushViewController:navigationController animated:true];
```

But after pushed the error seen is given below:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', reason: 'adding a root view controller SWRevealViewController: 0x137629e60 as a child of view controller:UINavigationController: 0x137658b50'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x1844bc2d8 0x195ce00e4 0x1844bc218 0x188f976c0 0x188f975b0 0x188f8cb00 0x188f8c700 0x188fea070 0x1000e39d8 0x188f31404 0x188f1a4e0 0x188f30da0 0x188f30a2c 0x188f29f68 0x188efd18c 0x18919e324 0x188efb6a0 0x184474240 0x1844734e4 0x184471594 0x18439d2d4 0x18dbb36fc 0x188f62fac 0x100108218 0x19635ea08)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: I think the problem is you are trying to push an `navigationController'. Try pushing directly on the `SWRevealViewController`

Comment: can u show your storyboard sequnece

Answer (score 1):

You made mistake is `nested` `UINavigationController` as its **recommended not to use more than a single UINavigationController while nesting**.

So simply use your `UIViewController` only rather than using `UINavigationcontroller` on `UINavigationcontroller`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your problem is but here is the version I am using with swift and it works.

```
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    let viewController = StartVC()
    let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
    window?.rootViewController = navigationController

    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

If you just want to push a view controller in from another view controller, here is how to do it:

```
    var newProfileVC = ProfileVC()
    newProfileVC.mainVCPointer = self
    navigationController?.pushViewController(newProfileVC, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are trying to push a `UINavigationController` instance into another instance of `UINavigationController`. This generates an internal inconsistency of the `UIViewController` hierarchy. Try this:

```
UIStoryboard *storyBoard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

UIViewController *yourNextViewController = (UIViewController *)[storyBoard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"historyGoodsView"];

SWRevealViewController *rootViewController = (SWRevealViewController *)[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]rootViewController];
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];

[navController pushViewController:yourNextViewController animated:YES];
```